# SwiperJS with react isn't showing next slide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, swiper.js

I am currently integrating SwiperJS with my ReactApp and everything is working except that it does not show the next slide. It will show the slides currently in display but when I slide over it does not show the next slides.
I'm using the default slider and sample code they have on the website but I can't seem to replicate their demo.
https://swiperjs.com/react

[Slide 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88teA.png)

[Slide 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMF5o.png)

In this example you can see that the first 3 slides are in display, but when I slide over it cuts off the edge of "Slide 3" and does not show "Slide 4".

**JSX** code

```
import "./aboutus.scss"
import { init } from "ityped"
import { useEffect,useRef } from "react"
import {Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react/swiper-react.js'
import { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/swiper.scss'; // core Swiper
import 'swiper/modules/navigation/navigation.scss'; // Navigation module
import 'swiper/modules/pagination/pagination.scss'; // Pagination module





export default function Aboutus() {

    const textRef = useRef();
    useEffect(()=> {
        init(textRef.current, { 
            showCursor: false,
            typeSpeed: 150, 
            strings: [' Boston.', ' Los Angeles.' ]
         })
    }, []);
    

    return (
        <div className="aboutus" id="aboutus">
            <div className="left">
                <div className="bio">
                        <div className="header">
                            <p >We are a K-POP Cover Dance Team in...</p>
                            <span ref={textRef} className="textref"> </span>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="right">
                <div>
                    <Swiper
                        className="swiper-wrapper"
                        spaceBetween={1}
                        slidesPerView={3}
                        onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
                        onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
                    >
                        <SwiperSlide className="swiper-slide">Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
                        <SwiperSlide className="swiper-slide">Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
                        <SwiperSlide className="swiper-slide">Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
                        <SwiperSlide className="swiper-slide">Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
                    </Swiper>
                </div>
            </div>     
        </div>
    )
}
```

**SCSS code**

```
    .right{
        flex: 0.5;
        border: solid red;
        height: 90%;
        background-color: aqua;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

        .swiper-wrapper{
            // width: 100%;
            // height: 100%;
            // overflow: hidden;
            // border: solid green;
            
            .swiper-slide{
                border: solid purple;
                // width: 100px;
                height: 300px;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Within my "index.html" file I had an "overflow-x: hidden" within my "" element which was causing the slides to cut off. I removed it and all the carousels are working!

Hope this solution helps anyone else struggling with this issue as well!